# How do create dynamic models in Golang?

Tags: sql-server, go, sqlx

I have a Rabbit MQ message queue that will give me random data sources like SQL Table, Oracle Table or Storedprocedure and whenever i get a data source i need to dynamically create the model and fetch the data from source db. I will be getting Source DB, Connection String, Table and parameters.

For Example: Students DB

```sql
Select * from dbo.Student_Grade (nolock) where grade >=B
```

I will not be knowning this Student_Grade table in advance, i will get it from the Rabbit MQ and my method has to connect to the db and execute the `dbo.Student_Grade (nolock)` where `grade >=B` sql statement and store the response in to other table or local redis

Comment: What have you tried? What problems have you run into? Can you show your code?

Comment: @Adrian i tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51731423/how-to-read-a-row-from-a-table-to-a-map-without-knowing-columns But what would be the return output column for this solution?